# Setting Up External DNS and Nameserver Through GoDaddy On a Dedicated Server

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, dns

I have setup a new dedicated server running Ubuntu 16.04 and Server pilot, Example IP of `111.222.333.444`

I purchased a domain through GoDaddy, will call this `example.com`.  I created 2 Hostname records: `NS1.EXAMPLE.COM` points to `111.222.333.444` and `NS2.EXAMPLE.COM` points to `111.222.333.444`

I left the name servers on the GoDaddy default and changed the record A to point to `111.222.333.444`

Then in Ubuntu, added "server" to /etc/hostname.  Changed the last line in /etc/hosts to `"111.222.333.444 server.example.com server"`.  Changed hostname to server.

Restarted services and rebooted server.

I then go to Namecheap and change my nameservers to `NS1.EXAMPLE.COM` and `NS2.EXAMPLE.COM`.

My sites cannot connect to the server, I'm missing something.

Been Googling this for hours.  Do I need to install Bind even though I don't want an internal DNS server?

Thank you in advance for the help!

UPDATE:

Testing with 2 domains, both registered through Namecheap, `test1.com` and `test2.com`

`test1.com` will load if I leave the nameservers to Namecheap default and add A record with IP `111.222.333.444`.

`test2.com` has the nameservers pointed to `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`.  The page will not connect when I go to `test2.com`, but it will connect when I go to `111.222.333.444`.  My server IP loads `test2.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to have 111.222.333.444 provide dns services, then it needs some sort of dns server, such as bind, to be running on it, and listening on port 53.

Your update for test1.com is how most do it. i.e. use some major dns service for the external DNS stuff.